# How to inherit one mock from another?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Say i have this example code:

```
interface IBase {
    int BaseProperty { get; }
}
interface IDerived : IBase {
    int DerivedProperty { get; }
}
```

and i like to write mocks for both interfaces.

Base mock is easy:

```
class BaseMock : Mock<IBase> {
    public int BaseProperty { get; set; } = 42;
    public BaseMock() {
        SetupGet(o => o.BaseProperty).Returns(BaseProperty);
    }
}
```

but im not sure how to correctly write derived mock:

```
class DerivedMock : Mock<IDerived> {
    public int BaseProperty { get; set; } = 42;
    public int DerivedProperty { get; set; } = 73;
    public DerivedMock() {
        // setups related to IBase
        SetupGet(o => o.BaseProperty).Returns(BaseProperty);

        // setups related to IDerived
        SetupGet(o => o.DerivedProperty).Returns(DerivedProperty);
    }
}
```

this implementation will work as expected, but im forced to copy bassically whole content of `BaseMock` class here and that is not DRY ...

ideally i would like to inherit `DerivedMock` from `BaseMock`, but then setups related to `IDerived` would not compile (`o` is `IBase` and i it to be `IDerived`)...

I appreciate any kick in the right direction :)

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it what exactly is your main problem that you want to solve. Do you want to Setup only those properties that are defined inside the `IDerived`?

Comment: @PeterCsala i want to reuse all setups defined in BaseMock ctor inside DerivedMock ctor without need to duplicate code

Comment: If you write individual tests, you create within each test your own mock setup. If you need some base data prepared that should be served by your mocks (just some POCOs) I would use some factory method that creates a bunch of data objects as needed or a library like [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) or [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture)

Answer (score 0):

You don't inherit from the `Mock` class. Instead you use Mock's `Object` property to get the mocked object. To reuse setting up `IBase` mock, you can do something like this:

```
    private static void SetupBase<T>(Mock<T> mock)
        where T : class, IBase
    {
        // setup base methods and properties
        mock.SetupGet(x => x.BaseProperty).Returns(1);
    }

    private static void SetupDerived(Mock<IDerived> mock)
    {
        SetupBase(mock);

        // setup derived methods and properties
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var derivedMock = new Mock<IDerived>();
        SetupDerived(derivedMock);
        var derived = derivedMock.Object;

        Assert.AreEqual(1, derived.BaseProperty);

        derivedMock.SetupGet(x => x.BaseProperty).Returns(2);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, derived.BaseProperty);
    }
```

Comment: interesting idea .... but in your version i cannot define "fallback" property that allows me to dynamically change mocked property return value ... i will post my refactoring later ...

Comment: You can change property return value at any time. `derivedMock.SetupGet(x => x.BaseProperty).Returns(value1)`. `derivedMock.SetupGet(x => x.DerivedProperty).Returns(value2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Rafał Rutkowski kicked me to right direction and i ended up with this code for anyone else interested:

```
interface IBase {
    int BaseProperty { get; }
}
interface IDerived : IBase {
    int DerivedProperty { get; }
}

class BaseMock : Mock<IBase>, IBase {
    public int BaseProperty { get; set; } = 42;

    public BaseMock() {
        SetupAll(this, this);
    }

    public static void SetupAll<TBase>([NotNull] Mock<TBase> mock, [NotNull] TBase instance)
        where TBase : class, IBase {
        mock.SetupGet(o => o.BaseProperty).Returns(instance.BaseProperty);
    }
}


class DerivedMock : Mock<IDerived>, IDerived {
    public int BaseProperty { get; set; } = 42;
    public int DerivedProperty { get; set; } = 73;

    public DerivedMock() {
        SetupAll(this, this);
    }

    public static void SetupAll<TDerived>([NotNull] Mock<TDerived> mock, [NotNull] TDerived instance) 
        where TDerived : class, IDerived {
        BaseMock.SetupAll(mock, instance);
        mock.SetupGet(o => o.DerivedProperty).Returns(instance.DerivedProperty);
    }
}

public class UnitTest1
{
    public void Test() {
        BaseMock baseMock = new BaseMock();
        IBase baseObject = baseMock.Object;

        baseMock.BaseProperty = 37;
        Assert.AreEqual(37, baseObject.BaseProperty);
        baseMock.VerifyGet(o => o.BaseProperty, Times.Never);
        
        // ----------------

        DerivedMock derivedMock = new DerivedMock();
        IDerived derivedObject = derivedMock.Object;

        derivedMock.BaseProperty = 42;
        derivedMock.DerivedProperty = 73;
        Assert.AreEqual(42, derivedObject.BaseProperty);
        Assert.AreEqual(73, derivedObject.DerivedProperty);
    }
}
```

reason why i wrote it this way is that i can dynamicall change property value AND verify that it was readed / written.

Comment: It seems a lots of code for a little gain. I do understand that you might have a lots of properties in reality. But for this particular example it seems like an overkill.